# How to use java scanner with string validation?

Tags: java, string, validation, java.util.scanner

I have the following code:

```
String f_name = "";
System.out.println(ANSI_PURPLE + "What is your first name?");
System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Type your name here (use only latin characters) > ");

while(!sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]*")) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option! ");
    System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Type your name here (use only latin characters) > ");
    f_name = sc.next().toUpperCase();
}


System.out.println("First Name = " + f_name);
```

The issue with the above code is that it would store what has previously added.

for example:

```
What is your first name?
 Type your name here (use only latin characters) > 123
 ERROR: Invalid option! 
 Type your name here (use only latin characters) > c
First Name = 123
```

How to fix so that the validation of latin characters will still work, redirect the user to same question if there is a mistake and store the correct value?

---

CORRECT ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:

```
...
while(!sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]*")) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option! ");
    System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Type your name here (use only latin characters) > ");
    sc.next();
}

f_name = sc.next().toUpperCase();
System.out.println("First Name = " + f_name);
```

Comment: How about adding `f_name = sc.next().toUpperCase();` after the loop?

Comment: Thanks for you answer @khelwood... It works great if the input is valid. If its not valid (e.g. `123456`) it will go on infinite loop

Comment: I didn't say remove `sc.next()` from _inside_ the loop.

Comment: oops! Works fine now thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]*")` returns true, that means the *next* input you read will be the one you want. So you need to read `f_name` in *after* the loop ends.

You still need `sc.next()` inside the loop to move past bad input; otherwise you will have an infinite loop.

By the way, perhaps you want to use `+` instead of `*` in your regular expression. `*` means "zero or more", and `+` means "one or more". I assume you want one or more characters to be input.

```
while (!sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option!");
    System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Type your name here (use only latin characters) > ");
    sc.next();
}

String f_name = sc.next().toUpperCase();
```